# get the full image path of the image stored in the PhotoGallery in Titanium

Tags: iphone, titanium

How to get the full image path of the image stored in the PhotoGallery in Titanium iphone?

Answer (score 0):

it cannot be done.

if you look at the [code in the mediaModule](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/MediaModule.m) you will see that the information related to the filePath is never returned on the object provided in the callback